# Missing } inserted \end{document} error with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, packages, texstudio

So I'm having some trouble with adding my bibliography to my document. I added this at te end of my document (just before `\end{document}`):

```
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,bedrijfsprofiel_biblio}
```

bedrijfsprofiel_biblio.bib is my file with my references in, I used this method before and didn't have this issue.
Everytime I try to compile I get the error `Missing } inserted. \end{document}` and `Missing { inserted. \end{document}` with a reference to the line that only contains `\end{document}`. When I comment the 2 lines where I add my bibliography, every thing is fine. What can be the cause of this problem.
These are the packages that I declared in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
```

This is the document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,kul]{kulakarticle}
```

It's in essence an article, with a bit changed for my uni.

Comment: Is `IEEEabrv` a `.bib` file?

Comment: no, I think it's a part of the IEEEtran style, but I'm not sure. But it worked before like this in other documents.

Comment: `\bibliography{}` should contain only your `.bib` file.

Comment: still the same error if I delete the IEEEabrv

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, [IEEEabrv](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEabrv.bib) is a `.bib` file that comes with the `IEEEtran` bundle. Assuming that the OP's `.bib` file is called `bedrijfsprofiel_biblio.bib` and that they have `IEEEtran` installed properly, `\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bedrijfsprofiel_biblio}` is **not** an error. The files `IEEEabrv.bib` and `IEEEfull.bib` are used to abbreviate or spell out in full names of journals in the bibliography according to official conventions (the IEEE usually wants abbreviated names) ...

Comment: ... The file will only do anything useful, however, if one used the strings in one's `.bib` file instead of giving the journal names directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turned out that the issue was hidden in code not shown (or even hinted at) in the question at all (see self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem I had wasn't with the bibliography after all, the problem was that in the author field, I used `\\` because there were to many to fit on 1 line. As a result there were issues with the bottom margins, because the names appear there also in this template.